# How to make a view 'portable' in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have in my index a place where I want to include a search form. Thing is this 'search form' needs to be in different sections of the site, so what I did was to create a controller and model for search form view. Now my problem is I don't know how to include it in my index (or in other parts of the site).

I already know it goes against the MVC pattern to load a controller from a view, so I stopped looking for that. I've done some research and the most common answer seems to be to 'reuse the model' but I'm not sure what that means. Should I copy the functions in the controller of the search form and include them in the index controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I think you should take a look at the template method, if you're not already using it.

http://williamsconcepts.com/ci/codeigniter/libraries/template/reference.html

This enables you to make custom templates and you can decide in your controller whether you want the search form in it.

If you'd rather do this in the view itself, you could try using this in your view

```
include(searchform.php)
```

Comment: thank you @Crowlix, i use include and it work. I know it's not the most advisable thing to do, so I'll definetely take a look at the template method. For now it is fixed but in long term I'll make sure to do what you suggested.

Comment: quick question, the template library you pointed at was last updated for ci 1.7? it works fine for latest 2.1? or do you know one that's more updated